# Accuracy of a naive bayes classifier

Tags: classification, naivebayes

I am familiar with the concept of calculating the accuracy of the naive bayes classifier using the number of training and test records in the confusion matrix. Mathematically, is there a concept of calculating the accuracy of a naive bayes classifier using only the training set? Any suggestions would be great.

Example training set:

```
 A    B    Class
 0    0     _
 1    1     +
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the training-set simply to train the model. Once you have trained the model. Then, you can use the testing-set to find out how accurate your model is. To accomplish this task you will have to keep track of the expected outcome of the testing-set.

```
A    B    Class
0    0     _
1    1     +
```

In the example,

1. Two features: A and B
2. Two documents: D1 (0,0) and D2 (1,1)
3. Two classes: - and +

Depending on the Naive Bayes algorithm you have implemented. You will take that training-set and fit it to your model.

Now, you also need a testing-set to make sure you can predict against your model.

```
   A    B    Class
D1 0    1     _
D2 1    0     +
```

Depending on how your model predicts these items you have to do a simple calculation where you compare predictions with expected.

[Some good info, Click HERE](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2013/03/25/why-accuracy-alone-bad-measure-classification-tasks-and-what-we-can-do-about-it/)